# How to pass req.params as an an argument to a middleware function?

Tags: javascript, express, express-validator

I'm trying to figure out a way to use req.params as an argument in my middleware. Take this (obviously broken) code for example:

```js
router.post('/:myParam', checkSchema(schemas[req.params.myParam]), async (req, res, next) => {
  // do stuff
})
```

The goal here is that I am using `express-validator` and I load a dynamic schema based on what param is passed. The above code is obviously broken because I don't yet have the scope to access the req variable, I'm just trying to illustrate what I'm trying to accomplish.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you know the possible params ahead, you could do something like the following:

```js
router.post("/:myParam", checkSchema("soccer"), async (req, res, next) => {});

//checkSchema.JS
    const soccerSchema = require("../schemas/soccerSchema");
    const swimmingSchema = require("../schemas/swimmingSchema");

    module.exports = function (schemaName) {
      return (req, res, next) => {
        const schemas = { soccer: soccerSchema, swimming: swimmingSchema };
        //You can access it here schemas[schemaName]
        console.log(schemas[schemaName]);
        next();
      };
    };
```

Answer (score 1):

You can directly call `schemas(req.params.myParam)` inside the `checkSchema` middleware since the middleware will have access to the request object.